# Vue.js 2.0 how can I get selected value from select2

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I'm trying to select multiple items from select2, but I don't know where the problem is. My parent component didn't get the selected values and I need it to pass all values selected. I'm using vue.js 2.1.0

**sub.vue**

```
<select2 :options="options" v-model="selected" name="options[]">
         <option disabled value="0">Select</option>
</select2>



         data(){
            return{
                selected: [],
                options: [],
            }
        },
        mounted(){
            this.fetchOptions(this.$route.params.id);
            this.fetchSelected(this.$route.params.id);
        },
        created(){
            this.fetchOptions(this.$route.params.id);
            this.fetchSelected(this.$route.params.id);
        },
        methods: {
            fetchOptions(id) {
                var that = this;
                $.get('/subject/' +id+ '/edit', function(data, status){
                    that.options = _.map(data.options, function (data) {
                        var pick = _.pick(data, 'name','id');
                        var opject = {id:pick.id, text:pick.name};
                        return opject
                    })
                })
            },
            fetchSelected(id) {
                var that = this;
                $.get('/subject/' +id+ '/edit', function(data, status){
                    that.selected = _.map(data.selected, function (data) {
                        var pick = _.pick(data, 'name','id');
                        var opject = {id:pick.id, text:pick.name};
                        return opject
                    })
                })
            },
        },
        components:{
            'select2': Select2
        },
```

**select.vue**

```
<template>
    <select multiple class="input-sm" :name="name" id="select2-template">
        <slot></slot>
    </select>
</template>
<style src="select2/dist/css/select2.min.css"></style>
<style src="select2-bootstrap-theme/dist/select2-bootstrap.min.css"></style>

<script>
    import Select2 from 'select2';

    export default{
        props: ['options', 'value', 'name'],
        template: '#select2-template',
        data(){
            return{
                msg: 'hello vue'
            }
        },
        mounted(){
            var vm = this;
            $(this.$el)
                .select2({theme: "bootstrap", data: this.options})
                .val(this.value)
                .trigger('change')
                .on('change', function () {
                    vm.$emit('input',  $(this).val())
                })
        },
        watch: {
            value: function (value) {
                if ([...value].sort().join(",") !== [...$(this.$el).val()].sort().join(","))
                    $(this.$el).val(value).trigger('change');
            },
            options: function (options) {
                $(this.$el).select2({ data: options })
            }
        },
        destroyed: function () {
            $(this.$el).off().select2('destroy')
        }
    }
</script>
```

**php code sub.php**

```
'selected' => $model->Users()->where('role', 'TE')
                    ->orderBy('name')
                    ->get(),
                'options' => User::where('role', 'TE')
                    ->orderBy('name')
                    ->get()
```

Comment: Don't mix `jQuery` and `Vue.js`...

Comment: @Cristy How would he use the select2 jQuery plugin otherwise?

Comment: @BertEvans Well, once you choose a framework you also choose the libraries and plugins that go with it. There are alternatives to `select2` for Vue, no need to include another 200kb of libraries just for a dropdown.